# Drag and Drop Files from Windows Explorer To Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop

I'm doing some old school IE and trying to get drag and drop from windows explorer to IE working. I'm getting the drop events but the `dataTransfer` object does not contain the file name(s). `getData("Text")` is also `null`. What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>DnD</title>
  <script src="scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="dropstuff">drop stuff here</div>
  <script>
    $(function () {
      var dropTarget = $("#dropstuff");

      dropTarget.bind("dragenter dragover", function () {
        window.event.returnValue = false;
        return false;
      });

      dropTarget.bind("drop", function (e) {
        window.event.returnValue = false;
        var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("Url");
        // file is null!
        return false;
      });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IE only supports drag and drop for some DOM elements, it has no such support for files until the next version IE10.

Comment: Didn't Microsoft completely cut off any interoperability between IE and Windows Explorer because of a lawsuit or something?

Answer (score 0):

IE is really bad at supporting things.

You should use special plugin, i.e. https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload or http://www.plupload.com/ or you might want to find solution on Flash. But that might take some time.

I suggest you fix this issue organizational way: advice users to use modern browsers by showing warning of partial funcionality compatibility in IE.